# Is it acceptable / legal for students to photograph their professors during class?

Tags: ethics, etiquette, legal-issues

Recently, I noticed a student taking a photo of me from her seat during class. I asked her while the class was working on groups if she indeed did do this and she confirmed, but downplayed her rationale but offered no real reason. I feel very uncomfortable with this as I did not give my consent and feel strongly I should have a voice in this action. I would never take a photo of any student without their permission/consent.

Did she behave break the law or etiquette?

Comment: In the reverse at least, student privacy laws *may* give them a right to not be photographed in your class.

Comment: Where in the world did this happen?

Comment: While this apparently doesn’t apply here, something I have experienced often is students photographing the blackboard (after asking for permission).

Comment: I vtc'd pending the jurisdiction in question, although I'm surprised two mods edited the question - which was only about breaking the law - to add in etiquette after a legal answer had already been given.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your local jurisdiction, of course, but typically she did not break the law. Once you are in a public place, your consent to being photographed isn't legally required anymore.

[Typical example](https://www.police.govt.nz/faq/what-are-rules-around-taking-photos-or-filming-public-place) (New Zealand):

> It is generally lawful to take photographs of people in public places without their consent. However, you must not film or take photos of people if they are in a place where they can expect privacy (such as a public changing area or toilet) and that person:
>
> - is naked, in underclothes, showering, toileting etc
> - is unaware of being filmed or photographed
> - has not given consent to be filmed or photographed.
>
> You should not take photos of people if:
>
> - they are in a place where they would expect reasonable privacy and publication would be highly offensive to an objective and reasonable person
> - it has potential to stop other people's use and enjoyment of the same place
> - you have no legitimate reason for taking the film or photos.
>
> However, you can take and/or publish photos or film of people where there is no expectation of privacy, such as a beach, shopping mall, park or other public place.

You are in a classroom, where there is probably no expectation of privacy ([example](https://www.edlawyer.com/eblackboard/2015/6/26/courts-clarify-privacy-rights-in-the-classroom) for the US), so your student did not break the law. If you feel strongly about it, consider if you ever took photos at a tourist attraction, you could easily have taken a photo of someone in the background. If this were illegal, you would need to approach them and get their consent - something that is highly impractical.

**That said**: your local jurisdiction might have prohibitions against sharing the photo, even if it doesn't prohibit taking the photo. Example for [Germany](https://allaboutberlin.com/guides/photography-laws-germany).

Comment: I think "you consent to being photographed" is slightly inaccurate, rather "your consent isn't legally required."

Comment: Thank you for this input. I appreciate your thoughtfulness and delineation of public vs. private facilities. Your response states "you should not take photos of people for: you have no legitimate reason for taking the film or photos." There was absolutely no legitimate reason. She offered nothing when I asked. […]

Comment: […] For me, I suppose I feel I should have a choice in this. Would you ever pull out your camera in the middle of a class and take a pic of a student without their knowledge or consent? For me, it's a matter of respect. I should think I should have a say if I appear on someone's social media

Comment: It also depends on what she was planning to *do* with the photo. Several countries (at least in the EU, probably in more places - which country are you in?) additionally have something called 'portrait right' - even if you're allowed to take photos in public space, if the person is clearly identifiable, that person would still have the right to object to publication (including on the internet). This does not prohibit making photos in public spaces that would not get published, though.

Comment: This *really* depends, as you say. In Germany, you have a "right to control pictures of you" (*Recht am Bild*), unless you are a public person. An instructor could probably demand to take down any pictures taken of them during class.

Comment: In addition, I suspect that jurisdictions also differ in whether they consider a classroom a public space or a private space. You can make valid arguments either way, so the legal answer depends on the local laws.

Comment: It's not clear whether a university classroom presents a public place. From the examples in the text, this term sounds limited to places where everybody is free to move anytime, e.g., a marketplace or a public sports field. In such places, there might be particular privacy-sensitive areas, such as toilets and changing areas.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper a university classroom is "private" if it's a private university, in which case taking photos can be illegal if you are trespassing and the landowner asks you to leave. But even for a private university the student is clearly not trespassing (and the professor is clearly not the landowner). So, still legal.

Comment: @Allure My concern also applies to public universities. Arguably, not every room in a public institution's facilties is a public place (my office is hopefully not).

Comment: @lighthousekeeper you could make an argument that your office is not a public place, but a classroom? I would like to see why you think it's not obvious a classroom is a public place.

Comment: @Allure I would define public as "open to the general public", which does not apply to a classroom - under normal circumstances, only staff members and currently-enrolled students have a business of being there.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper *only staff members and currently-enrolled students have a business of being there* Really? In many classes I've attended, anyone can "kibitz" if they want to; it's just a matter of walking in. You could say they have no business being there, but they are allowed to be there as long as they don't cause a disturbance - I imagine this is especially the case in countries where tertiary education is free.

Comment: @henning the student in the example isn't sharing the photo though, only taking them.

Comment: @user153249 "should not" is not the same as "must not" - it's silly for a student to take a photo of an instructor who's clearly said they don't want to be photographed, so the student "should not" do it - but they still can if they're foolhardy enough. As for *appear on someone's social media*, that's something else, there are different laws that apply to sharing photos (see comment by henning above). For that you'll have to add more details to the OP, I'm afraid.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper some Googling (search phrase "reasonable expectation of privacy classroom") landed on these two pages https://www.edlawyer.com/eblackboard/2015/6/26/courts-clarify-privacy-rights-in-the-classroom and https://news.schoolsdo.org/2017/09/no-reasonable-expectation-of-privacy-in-a-classroom/ clearly establishing that there is no reasonable expectation of privacy in a classroom. I can edit it into the answer if you like, although I am still quite surprised it's a contentious statement.

Comment: @Allure Alright, then in that particular jurisdiction in the US, a classroom counts as public place (and editing that into the answer would improve it). In the countries I'm more familiar with, which are in Europe, kibitzing might be tolerated, but that's a different question of whether it's formally OK. For the universities where I found information online, they generally allow it for some but not all course sessions, and sometimes only after a special registration. So it's still not clear if the lecture hall itself counts as a public place.

Comment: @Allure those links are US cases. The whole world is not like the US. I am no lawyer, but I suspect that question would have a very different answer in Germany. So that is why it is controversial.

Comment: A space can be 'public' in the sense of not expecting privacy, while still not being 'public' in the sense that just anyone can walk in there.

Comment: Are you sure the pictures were of you and not your lecture notes on the board behind them?